# REST API with Struts

Tags: rest, struts2, struts

I'm trying to add a REST API to an existing struts 2 application.

The idea is to have part of the application using standard struts mapping, and another part using REST.

So I used the [struts2-rest-plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html) plugin, and added the following configuration:

**struts.xml:**

```
<constant name="rest" value="org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionMapper"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.class"   
  value="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.PrefixBasedActionMapper"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.prefixMapping" value="/rest:rest,/:struts"/>
```

**struts.properties:**

```
struts.action.extension=,htm,action,xml,json
```

**TasksController.java:**

```
package xxx.common.webservice.rest;

public class TasksController implements ModelDriven<Task> {

  public String update() {
    return "UPDATE";
  }

  // Handles /tasks/{id} GET requests
  public String show() {
    return "YES";
  }

  @Override
  public Task getModel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }

}
```

With this configuration, the basic struts action work, but I can't get the REST actions to work.
I also tried different **struts.xml** configurations (including the convention plugin options), but without any success, the mappings are never shown with the [config-brower plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/config-browser-plugin.html).

Any idea of what I have missed or done wrong?

Comment: what you mean by "can't get the REST actions to work"? a bit explanation will help

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the rest actions always return a 404 error (GET and POST), or a 403 error (PUT and DELETE).

Comment: i am not sure how REST work but you need to be careful that every action should have there namespace defined.Hope some one else can look into this

Comment: Check the user list archives for combining REST with "regular" actions; I can play with this over the weekend as I did the exact same thing but don't remember how at the moment :(

Comment: I'm also trying the same, did one had any success.

Comment: @XCoder, I posted my configuration, perhaps you will find something useful. Feel free to correct it or ask any question.

Comment: @nicompte I personally used WildCard Mappings http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html for REST type URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It finally worked, but it was a while ago and I don't remember exactly what I did, here is my configuration, hope this helps.

**struts.xml**

```
<constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="webservice"/>
<constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Controller"/>
<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="rest-default"/>


<constant name="struts.mapper.class" value="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.PrefixBasedActionMapper" />
<constant name="struts.mapper.prefixMapping" value="/rest:rest,:struts" />

<package name="home" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    ...
</package>
```

**TaskController.java**

```
package com.test.webservice.rest;

public class TaskController extends RestActionSupport implements
    ModelDriven<TaskDTO> {
      public final HttpHeaderResult show() {
         ...
      }
    ...
}
```